# Rails update remove number from an array attribute?

Tags: arrays, ruby, destroy

Is there a way to remove a number from an attibute array in an update?  For example, if I want to update all of an alchy's booze stashes if he runs out of a particular type of booze:

```
Alchy has_many :stashes

Stash.available_booze_types = [] (filled with booze.ids)

Booze is also a class

@booze.id = 7

if @booze.is_all_gone
  @alchy.stashes.update(available_booze_types: "remove @booze.id")
end
```

update:  @booze.id may or may not be present in the available_booze_types array

... so if @booze.id was in any of the Alchy.stash instances (in the available_booze_types attribute array), it would be removed.

Comment: I think more details are needed. What are `@alchy` and `@alchy.stashes` (class)? what are you exactly trying to do? an example with the expected result would be useful.

Comment: i've updated the questions, thanks!

Comment: It is still really confusing. Is available_booze_types a class or instance attribute? In your code it is a class attribute, but then I don't understand why you need to update it for every stashes. Can you please clarify what the relations of your applications are and what the classes look like?

Comment: available_booze_types is an instance attribute, and the code is just for example sake.   I want to search through all of the alchy's stashes, and if the booze instance id used to be in any of the alchy's stashes available_booze_types, i would like to remove it.   i'm a hobbyist developer on my first project

Comment: It is still not clear to me how your application is set up. You should paste your classes definitions instead of some confusing and inaccuracy pseudocode. It is really difficult to understand it at the moment. I have tried to answer you anyway. Hope that help. Otherwise, please write your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want in the following way:

```
if @booze.is_all_gone
  @alchy.stashes.each do |stash|
    stash.available_booze_types.delete(@booze.id)
  end
end
```

However, it looks to me like there are better ways to do what you are trying to do. Rails gives you something like that array by using relations. Also, the data in the array will be lost if you reset the app (if as I understand `available_booze_types` is an attribute which is not stored in a database). If your application is correctly set up (an stash has many boozes), an scope like the following in `Stash` class seems to me like the correct approach:

```
scope :available_boozes, -> { joins(:boozes).where("number > ?", 0) }
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
@alchy.stashes.available_boozes
```

which would only return the ones that are available.

Comment: thanks for effort!  sry for pseudocode.   i forgot that i actually do have a relationship with booze!   and in my real code it's a belongs to, and so i don't have to search through all of the stashes looking for the booze.   i can just go to the one stash of booze and remove it.